# Changing keyboard shortcut of "Available databases" in SQL Management Studio

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ssms

Please read my question before posting general help links.

I can't change or remove the shortcut CTRL+U from "Available databases" in the SQL Editor toolbar. (I want CTRL+U to unindent the selection in the text editor.)

What I tried:

- I assigned CTRL+U to the unindentation command, but still CTRL+U just moves the focus to the "Available databases" combo box. (I checked and I set up my shortcut correctly, actually I set up CTRL+I for indent and it works fine.)
- I tried to find CTRL+U in Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard with all places, only my definition shows up.
- I tried to find "Available databases" in Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard with "...containing" set to "database" (checked all entries) and "available" (again, checked all entries).
- I went to tool bar customization, selected the component, but no keyboard shortcut option/menu/button there. The "Keyboard" button only opens Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard with nothing set.

I actually do use "Available databases" every once in a while, so I rather not delete it from the tool bar.

Anyone have any feasible options apart from the above?

Comment: Looks like a [bug in SSMS](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/360460/ctrl-u). The fact that it was reported cca. 2008 and is still here is rather disheartening.

Comment: I changed that particular shortcut to ALT-D on one of my earlier installs of SQL Studio (the one before 2012) I dont remember having any issues with this, using the normal option-keyboard setup. But this is a new install and I cant remember. I cant even find the element called Available Databases anymore.
Point being: It can be done or at least; it could be done in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can "debug" and analyse your shortcut assignments with [SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com/) add-in for SSMS.
(I am developer of it). It has "Dump Shortcuts" function which will allow you to get quick overview which functions Ctrl-U is assigned to and you can also use it to re-define shortcuts.

Comment: FYI, I did a dump, and the resulting SQL Script causes SSMS to crash.

Comment: The resulting script is just a text pasted to newly created editor window. What do you mean under "script causes ssms to crash ?". Script is not intended to be run under SSMS. It is just information dump. Is there some misunderstanding ?

Comment: @andrei_rantsevich I know.  It was strange as heck.  It scripted out, I started to scroll down, and SSMS crashed.  I wasn't trying to run it, just view it.

Comment: (love the tool otherwise - it's freaking awesome)

Comment: If error persists, please contact me via support@ email, otherwise it will be off topic here. Thank you !